# Flutter App Installed and Done but not Disabled Open Option

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am working with flutter currently and everything was fine suddenly when I uninstalled the app from the device and rerun flutter run from the terminal it's suddenly not able to install the apk.

maybe when i including firebase in the flutter app then i facing this error.

Want to Know where is wrong my device or flutter code or something......

Comment: Check out this page - [Flutter Release App Not Opening After Install](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75223)

Answer (score 0):

can show how the error appears in the debug console.
maybe you can try to follow on the documentation page [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview)